# How to add notepad++ to the right click menu in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

**I don't know if this is the right forum for this question, although it is related to Windows XP**

I want to add notepad++ to the right click (new menu) in Windows XP, I have followed tutorials like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/Windows-Vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-Vista/) (there are similar articles out there that describe the same steps and say that it will work on XP, this article is on many websites, because bloggers love to copy and paste :D)

but this kind of tutorials don't work on XP, I don't want to download software (Even if they are free) because I have tried some of these programs and they don't work either

I have Windows XP Pro, sp2, 32-bit

Comment: Why stay on SP2?

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from uninstalling Notepad++ and reinstalling it?  It adds the shortcut automatically on install from my experience.

Comment: Do you want for any file, or a specifc extension.

Comment: @kyle my internet speed is so slow, it will take forever to upgrade to sp3

Comment: @techie007 no it does not add a shortcut (on my pc at least)

Comment: @Zoredache i haven't understand your question sir, i just want to add notepad++ to the right click menu, just like when you right click and choose create a text document you know, i just want to right click and open a notepad++ file

Comment: @Eli What version of Notepad++ are you using?

Comment: @techie007 Notepad++ v5.9.3 ... i tried to reinstall it long time ago, i won't try now coz i have many plugins you know so i need a more practical solution :)